# Get single attribute in model using Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Schemas : StepSchema, StepRelationshipSchema

```
var StepSchema = new Schema(
    {        
        name:           { type: String, required: true },
        description:    { type: String, default: '' },
        isVisible:      { type: Boolean, default: true }
    }, options
);


var StepRelationshipSchema = new Schema(
    {        
        workflowId:     { type: String, required: true },
        stepId:         { type: String, required: true },
        prevSteps:      [ Schema.Types.Mixed ] ,
        nextSteps:      [ Schema.Types.Mixed ] ,
        gotoStep:       { type: String, default: '' }
    }, options
);
```

In StepSchema, I want to create a static method to get nextSteps in StepRelationshipSchema.
Can I use this, thank you so much.

```
StepSchema.statics.getNextSteps = function(workflowId, currStepId) {
    return StepRelationship.findOne({
        workflowId: workflowId,
        stepId:     currStepId
    }).nextSteps
};
```

Comment: `findOne` is async so you need to use a callback instead of returning the value.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you.
So, in may routes, I will exec() this async then using Promise to handle retrive data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohnnyHK suggested in his comments, **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)** is async thus you need to use a callback function as follows:

```
// create a query for next stepswith a blogpost _id matching workflowId and currStepId
schema.statics.getNextSteps = function (workflowId, currStepId, callback) {
    return this.model('StepRelationship').findOne({
        workflowId: workflowId,
        stepId:     currStepId
    }, callback);
}
```